# Microsoft Graph API Webhooks - How to find who deleted calendar event

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, outlook-restapi

We are subscribing(using Graph API Webhooks) to calendar events that are deleted by the user. When the listener receive notification payload, is there a way to find our who(which user) deleted the calendar event?

Comment: For clarification, are you asking whether there is a way for the notification payload to contain the identity of the user that deleted the item?

Comment: Yes, if there is a way for the notification payload to contain the identity of the user that deleted the item? (or) is there a way to retrieve details of a deleted event based on event id present in Notification payload.

Comment: No, you won't be able to get that from the notification itself. You'd need to provide much more information about your scenario to help us  understand what is possible and how it is possible. What identity is subscribing to the webhook? Does the identity access its own resources or resources owned by someone else? You really need to provide a full description of your scenario and what you've tried thus far.

Comment: Thank you Michael for prompt response. let me see if i can explain in detail.

we are subscribing to 20K+ user's calendar events(only few type of events)
when the event notification is received, we need to take further action depending on change type(create/update/delete).

Since the notification payload will have an outlook event id, we can retrieve more details about the event using Graph API and take appropriate action but for deleted events, when graph API is queried using event id, graph API doesn't return any data because the event is already deleted.

question in next comment.

Comment: Question 1: Is there a way to query Graph API to retrieve deleted event details(like subject, start&End time etc) using the event id(that was received from Notification payload)
Question 2: we would like to take action only if the user intentionally deletes the event from their calendar(no action necessary if a process deletes the event using Graph API). is there a way to know the identity of user who deleted a specific event?

I can query Graph API to retrieve 'deleted messages' from deleted messages folder but NOT 'deleted events'.

Any suggestion would be much appreciated. Thanks!!

Comment: I was hoping to access the deleteditems folder but it is typed on Graph to only give us access to messages. Bummer. I'd hope that it was available. We need a proper Folder API.So for Q1, no way to get the deleted event that I know of. For Q2, do you have all control over which applications have access to a user's calendar? If so, you could make applications that delete events leave some sort of signature on an event (using an extension property) and then assume all other deleted events were done by the user. That's a brittle solution. There's nothing left to determine who deleted an event.

Comment: Thanks Michael, For Q2, since we can't retrieve details of a deleted event, we have no way of knowing who deleted the event even if we have an extension property.

Answer (score 0):

To recap the conversation in the comments. It is not possible today to retrieve details for a deleted event. There is an existing [uservoice entry](https://microsoftgraph.uservoice.com/forums/920506-microsoft-graph-feature-requests/suggestions/20440105-get-deleted-events) for which you can vote to help prioritize it. Voting for it will also keep you posted of updates.